# How to limit an AWS service to an organisation's users maintained by the Google Suite?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, saml, amazon-cognito

I'm confused how to simply authenticate an @example.com employee, in order to allow access to an internal service https://stage.example.com. The user experience I want; is for the employee to click a "Login with Google" button (preferably it would just automatically log the user in) and instantly have access based on his/her login email.

What do I need to implement?

- Something with SAML? https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#AppsList:serviceType=SAML_APPS
- Something with API credentials? https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
- Something with AWS Cognito? https://ap-southeast-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cognito
- Something to do with provider IDs? https://github.com/laardee/serverless-authentication-boilerplate
- Something to do with https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js & GAPI.auth2's **hosted_domain**?

Basically I want to get away from having duplicated users in AWS IAM. We want the canonical source of users in the company as https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#UserList

The idea being, when the employee leaves the company, the ex-employee is removed and access to https://stage.spuul.com & such internal services are withdrawn.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a step by step documentation explaining the setup here [AWS & Google Apps Federation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-single-sign-on-to-aws-using-google-apps/)

SAML is what you need to setup

Comment: Whoa, this is an astonishingly long and complex guide. Isn't there a simpler way? I still don't quite understand what the login process looks like for the Google suite user upon https://stage.example.com. What implements the login form ?